# OCMock does not return stubbed value in a new instance

Tags: ocmock

I have the below class written

```
@implementation B

- (NSString *)returnMock{
    return @"BBB";
}

@end
```

And I have the below test written:

```
- (void)testB {
    id mockB = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[B class]];
    [[[mockB stub] andReturn:@"mock"] returnMock];

    //This check is a pass
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"mock", [mockB returnMock]);

    B *b = [[B alloc] init];
    //This check is a fail
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"mock", [b returnMock]);
}
```

As I understand that, if a mock is created for a class and then for any new instance of it will refer to the mocked class.

If this is not true, can anyone help me in making the second assert to pass after a new instance is created.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A mock object can be used *instead* of an instance of the class. Creating a mock object does not affect instances of the class. If you want to mock methods in an existing instance you must use a partial mock *for that specific instance*.